# How to align product image, prices etc of b2b web app using css, bootstrap property?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on UI of some ecommerce web app products page. I want to align the product image, price, discounted price, description whatever the properties of a product is having. Currently, div is not equally aligned and I am not getting what css or bootstrap property should be used to equally align the elements to display over the UI.

This is the HTML. This div is repeating to display products.

```
<div class="col-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between border-bottom border-right">
    <div class="force-wrap"> 
        <a href="javascript:toDetailScreen(63141, false);">Test Catalog</a>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:toItemDetailScreen(&quot;63141-1&quot;)">
            <img src="/productimages/74616BDB-99E0-4FD4-9B07-1EDF7F21E099.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="my-2">
        <span class="font-weight-bold h6" style="opacity:0.5;">MSRP&nbsp;<s>$78.12</s></span>
    </div>
    <div class="my-2">
        <span class="font-weight-bold h5" style="color:red;">$69.13</span>
    </div>
    <div class="force-wrap">
        <h6>Test Catalog</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="force-wrap">ASU-GT730-SL-2GD5-BRK ASUS GF GT730 2GB GDDR5 PCIe - Open Box</div> 
    <div>
        <h6>
            <strong>ASUS INC. / ASUS INC.</strong> ASU-GT730-SL-2GD5-BRK
        </h6>
    </div>  
    <div class="d-flex flex-row my-3">
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button" href="javascript:void(0);">Details</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pl-3">
            <a title="Add To Cart" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add To Cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of products]